# URL change when put into <iframe>

Tags: html, iframe

I am trying to use an iframe, and for some reason the URL I'm putting in is changing to this really odd version.

This is the URL in my source:

```
<iframe width="962" height="830" src="http://www.domain.com/fdic_edie_the_estimator.aspx#action=resize|value=523px|msg_id=3"></iframe>
```

And this is what I get afterwards:

```
<iframe id="edieframe" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" name="edieframe" border="0" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" style="width: 625px; height: 523px; border: medium none;" src="http://www2.fdic.gov/EDIE-WL/intro.html#id=57861-3|origin=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.domain.com%2Ffdic_edie_the_estimator.aspx%23action%3Dresize%7Cvalue%3D523px%7Cmsg_id%3D3">
```

Is there some rule on the site that I'm missing? Is there an iframe in an iframe?

The header for the page comes up, but none of the content.

Let me know if you need more information.

Comment: It is changing after what ? What causes the url to change ? I mean is it the source code of your original page that changes ?

Comment: I've tried it myself and I don't experience any changes. How do you publish this code ?